# Compare rows in SQL

Tags: sql, compare

I have got a sample table like this.

```
ID           Name
1            Jane  
2            John
3            Kevin
4            George
5            Jane
```

The result I would like to get from the query would be a table of two values:

```
ID           Name
1            Jane
5            Jane
```

I know this could be done using 2 copies of a table and then comparing names of one and the other table but I couldn't get this working, though.

--

Sorry, didn't add this. I want to get all duplicate values.

I can see all the responses about duplicates and so on, I've seen the post on stackoverflow about finding duplicates using count(*) but I wonder whether it could be done by creating two copies of the table (say t and tt) and then checking t.name = tt.name?

Comment: You know the Name beforehand or you want all the duplicate values?

Comment: You need to show some effort first; I'd say that people don't just give answers without seeing some effort first, but that's clearly not the case here :P  (And before anyone gets any ideas and decides to revenge downvote me *again* today, no, I didn't downvote any of the answers, despite being tempted)

Comment: I have been trying to solve this thing for like 2 hours now. It's quite simple but can't get this working. I've tried inner joins, getting two tables and then in WHERE clause checking if names match - it doesn't work unfortunately. Hence my question here.

Comment: @Neutrino you can use inner joins see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually recommend using `Joins` rather than `exist,in or not in` in the codes.

```
 Select A.ID,B.Name from Tablename A
    inner join Tablename B
    on A.Name = B.Name
     where a.id <> b.id
```

and

I don't usually recommend this, ID's should normally be joined rather than the name.
here is the [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25036e/1)

Comment: @Neutrino what's wrong with `<>`? `<>` means `not equal` or `!=`, try using those if you do not want the term `<>` I'm just not sure about those because i normally use `<>`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, it's just that the question I posted is part of my uni homework and <> wasn't used in previous tasks so it seemed awkward to me.

Comment: you can find alternatives to `<>` in the internet. but having the same function the word 'not equal'

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is by using `EXISTS()`.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tablename a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    tableName b
            WHERE   a.Name = b.name
            GROUP   BY Name
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28e729/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM table1
WHERE Name IN
 (SELECT Name
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY Name
  HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
 )
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: @downvoter, please explain, do you think is there anything wrong with this answer?

Comment: there are unreasonable downvoters here my answer also been downvoted 6 times -_-

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE A,
(
SELECT NAME,COUNT(*)
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) B
WHERE A.NAME = B.NAME;
```